# HiveSQLException: cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MAX' '(' in expression specification

Tags: hadoop, hive, greatest-n-per-group, hiveql

I'm trying to get the maximum value of a count. The code is as follows

```
SELECT coachID, COUNT(coachID)
FROM coaches_awards GROUP BY coachID
HAVING COUNT(coachID) = 
(
   SELECT MAX(t2.awards)
    FROM (
             SELECT coachID, count(coachID) as awards
             FROM coaches_awards
             GROUP BY coachID
          ) t2
);
```

Yet something keeps failing. The inner query works and gives the answer that I want and the outer query will work if the inner query is replaced by the number required. So I'm assuming I've made some syntax error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for one row, why not do:

```
SELECT coachID, COUNT(coachID) as cnt
FROM coaches_awards
GROUP BY coachID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want ties, then use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM (SELECT coachID, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM coaches_awards
      GROUP BY coachID
     ) ca
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I thought about just using the Limit but.. I feel like I'm taking the easy way out.

Comment: "order by" clause will force Hive to pass all data through one reducer, so if number of coaches is very high this can become time consuming.